# Bootstrap popover only works on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been having a hard time getting Bootstraps popover's to show on click and not on hover.  I looked at the example on this page.
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover&stacked=h

I have copied over the exact script src links from the example as well as the meta and link lines.  I also initialize the popover to no avail.  Here is a simplified version of what I'm working with.

```
    <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="style.css" />     
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta charset="utf-8"> 
            
    </head>           
    <body>
                    <div id="container">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-trigger="click" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>
                    </div>
                    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script>
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
                                });
                    </script>
               </body>
```

I don't know if this is a normal thing to do or not but i tried opening up the page, right clicking the a element and clicking inspect(in chrome.)  In the bottom right it shows me two errors.

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function

It cant find JQuery?  Its certainly there.  The element shows and the text reads when I hover over it and nothing happens when I click it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the jQuery script first:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This error is logged to the console on page load:

```
    Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

Meaning the bootstrap js is looking for the jquery object.